# get error on click on last checkbox in list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a strange problem..I have a list view that contains checkboxes..I want user select them and then I get selected items neme and add them to a loop..I used `ArrayAdapter` to do that every think is good but when I check last item for the first time I get error but If I check other checkboxes for the first time I didnot get error..Here Is on clicklistener

```
    package co.tosca.persianpoem;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

      private final List<String> list;
      private final Activity context;
      public ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      public ArrayList<String> main_db_id = new ArrayList<String>();
      public List<String> database_ids = new ArrayList<String>();

      public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.database_list_item, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        persian_poem_class main=new persian_poem_class(context);
        String mySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT id as _id "+","+ClubCP.COLUMN_POET_ID+","+ClubCP.COLUMN_PARENT_ID
                + " from cat"
                + " where " + ClubCP.COLUMN_PARENT_ID+"= 0 "
                + " order by " + ClubCP.COLUMN_POET_ID;
        Cursor c= main.getData(mySQL);

        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            main_db_id.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ClubCP.COLUMN_POET_ID))); //add the item
             c.moveToNext();
        }
        Log.i("main_db_id", main_db_id.toString());
        File path=new File(ClubCP.SDcardPath+"/temp/database/");
       database_ids =   main.directoryPath(path,true);
        Log.i("database_ids", database_ids.toString());
      }



      public ArrayList<String> getSelectedItems(){
      return items;
      }




      @Override
      public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View itemView = convertView ;
          final int pos =position;
            if (itemView == null) {


            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            itemView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.database_list_item, null);

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chk_database_list_item);
            TextView tv =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_database_status);
            Log.i("aray adapter","set caption");
            cb.setText(list.get(position));

            for(int i=0;i<database_ids.size();i++){
                boolean found = false;
                for(int j=0;j<main_db_id.size();j++){
                        if((database_ids.get(position).equals(main_db_id.get(j)))){
                                found = true;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if(found) {
                        tv.setText(context.getString(R.string.is_in_db));
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(context.getString(R.color.red)));
                } else {
                    tv.setText(context.getString(R.string.is_not_in_database));
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(context.getString(R.color.green)));                                            
                }
        }


            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox myCb = (CheckBox)v;

                    if (myCb.isChecked()) {
                        items.add(pos, list.get(pos));
                        Toast.makeText(context, items.toString(), 1).show();
                    } else {
                        items.remove(pos);
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

and here Is error

```
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:143)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at co.tosca.persianpoem.InteractiveArrayAdapter$1.onClick(InteractiveArrayAdapter.java:97)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-10 10:24:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It says out of bundry so I think problem Is with add items in listview but dont know why :(

and here is a new logcat

```
04-10 20:23:14.947: D/dalvikvm(7732): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 3% free 7646K/7875K, paused 23ms
04-10 20:23:14.947: I/dalvikvm-heap(7732): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.968MB for 1536016-byte allocation
04-10 20:23:14.977: D/dalvikvm(7732): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 9145K/9415K, paused 1ms+1ms
04-10 20:23:15.097: D/libEGL(7732): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-10 20:23:15.117: D/libEGL(7732): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
04-10 20:23:15.137: D/libEGL(7732): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
04-10 20:23:15.147: D/libEGL(7732): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
04-10 20:23:15.227: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7732): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-10 20:23:15.247: D/OpenGLRenderer(7732): Enabling debug mode 0
04-10 20:23:17.087: D/dalvikvm(7732): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 3% free 9167K/9415K, paused 12ms
04-10 20:23:17.097: I/dalvikvm-heap(7732): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.454MB for 1536016-byte allocation
04-10 20:23:17.127: D/dalvikvm(7732): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10667K/10951K, paused 2ms+5ms
04-10 20:23:17.177: D/TextLayoutCache(7732): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
04-10 20:23:17.197: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7732): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-10 20:23:17.338: D/OpenGLRenderer(7732): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-10 20:23:19.057: I/file_list(7732): [khiam.db, prvin-aEtsami.db]
04-10 20:23:19.057: I/main_db_id(7732): [3]
04-10 20:23:19.077: I/database_ids(7732): [3, 8]
04-10 20:23:19.087: I/aray adapter(7732): set caption
04-10 20:23:19.107: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7732): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-10 20:23:19.117: I/aray adapter(7732): set caption
04-10 20:23:19.137: I/aray adapter(7732): set caption
04-10 20:23:19.297: D/OpenGLRenderer(7732): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-10 20:23:20.387: I/getSelectedItems_befor(7732): []
04-10 20:23:20.387: I/list(7732): [khiam.db, prvin-aEtsami.db]
04-10 20:23:20.387: D/AndroidRuntime(7732): Shutting down VM
04-10 20:23:20.387: W/dalvikvm(7732): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:143)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at co.tosca.persianpoem.InteractiveArrayAdapter$1.onClick(InteractiveArrayAdapter.java:102)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-10 20:23:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the structure of `main_db_id`?

Answer (score 2):

```
items = ( items == null ) ? new ArrayList<Object>(list.size) : items;
```

Do this while initializing the item. Hope this will help. You are trying to add an Item to an `ArrayList` that doesn't have the position that you are mentioning in the `add` Command. Try to add the above line as the first statement in your `getView` method. And also Instead of add use `items.set(pos, list.get(pos));`

Comment: I tried this but I get "The blank final field list may not have been initialized"

Comment: It should be inside getView method

Comment: I added your code but still get error..what If I use an if statement ?

Comment: Thanks for your help I must change your code to use it ..I changed it to `items = ( items == null ) ? new ArrayList<String>(list.size()) : items;` but I still get same error..

Comment: Thanks my friend..I added it to my question